# computing $L^p-$norm of nice function.

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

Suppose that $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a smooth compactly supported function,  specifically, $f=1$ on $[-1/2, 1/2)$ and the support of $f$ is contained in $[-1,1].$

Suppose that $g$ is smooth and  compactly supported function on $[0, 2\pi).$

For $n\ne m \in \mathbb Z,$ put $F(\xi)=f(\xi-n)\cdot \widehat{g}(\xi-m), \xi \in \mathbb R.$. (Here $\widehat{\cdot}$ denote the Fourier transform)

> My question: Can we say that $\int_{\mathbb R}|F(\xi)|^p d\xi \leq C \frac{1}{\big(1+ (n-m)^2\big)^{\frac{s+2}{2p}}}$ for $s\geq 0$?

My attempts: I think both $f$ and $\widehat{g} $ are both Schwartz class function and its product as well.  So it is $L^p$ integrable. How can I get the decay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, $\hat{g}$ is a Schwartz function. In particular, for every $s \geq 0$, there exists $C_s > 0$ such that:
$$ \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}, \quad |\hat{g}(\xi)| \leq (1+|\xi|^2)^{-\frac s 2}.$$
Since $f$ is compactly supported in $[-1,1]$, $F = 0$ on $(-\infty,n-1] \cup [n+1,\infty)$. Hence, for $p \geq 1$,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |F(\xi)|^p \mathrm{d}\xi
= 
\int_{n-1}^{n+1} |F(\xi)|^p \mathrm{d}\xi
\leq 2 \|f\|_{L^\infty(-1,1)}^p \int_{-1}^{+1} |\hat{g}((n-m)+\xi')|^p \mathrm{d}\xi'.
$$
Combining both bounds readily implies that
$$
\forall s \geq 0, \exists C_s' > 0,
\quad
\| F \|_{L^p} \leq \frac{C_s'}{(1+(n-m)^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}},
$$
which implies the bound you are looking for (since this one is valid for all $s \geq 0$).

Comment: Thanks. How can we mange: $|\hat{g}(n-m+ \xi')| \leq 1/ [(n-m+ \xi')^2+1]^{s/2}$? I might need to use $\xi' \in (-1,1)$. but how? Thanks, please can you explain a bit?

Comment: If $|n-m| \geq 2$, then $|\xi'| \leq \frac 12 |n-m|$ so $|n-m+\xi'| \geq \frac 12 |n-m|$, so you have your bound (up to some constant). If $|n-m|\leq 2$, use instead $(1+(\cdots)^2) \geq 1$ which gives you a uniform bound when $n \approx m$.